# product details page returns blank when clicked on product resulting from search results in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem in my magento site , when i click on the product through categories the product details opens up . but when i search a product through search bar and click on the search result products, product detail doesnt show up , it gives me a blank page.
All the products are set to "catalog,search".

and i looked into

```
      "frontend\default\modern\template\catalog/product/view.phtml"
```

i could not find anything out of the ordinary in view.phtml

Can anybody give me a hint as to where should i start for debugging this problem?

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a php error since the header and footer display. What is the url for a product detail page (that work) and what is the url for that product when you do a search?

Answer (score 0):

open index.php and uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` also, open up .htaccess and add `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true`

Reload and see if you get any error messages, if not, check your webserver error logs or Magento exception.log file.

Comment: By blank, i mean only the product description is not displayed, all the other content's are displayed (header, footer..)

Comment: Thats weird, what if you try this on the view.phtml `var_dump($product->toArray())`

Comment: I am having the same problem,also I trued putting var_dump($_product->toArray()) on my view.phtml file...its dumping an array which means the product is actually retrieved without errors but it wont display it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is here, but to start with debugging I think its a good idea to set a break point at the code->Core->Mage->CatalogSearch->ResultController.php->indexAction().
Assuming the action attribute on the form is set to http://www.yourwebsite.com/catalogsearch/result/

Hope that helps .

Cheers,
Swapna

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

go to admin panel =>> manage products =>> select product which showing blank page =>> go to design from left side =>> set values of Custom Design, date and page layout...its done...